# Storing list of entity over joined tables

Tags: sql, arrays, object, relational-database

## Backgroud

In essence, I want to store something like:

```
{
  id : 1, 
  name : 'john', 
  favorite_pets : ['cat', 'dog'], 
  favorite_colors : ['red', 'white', 'green']
}
```

In a relational database with three tables:

Table main:

```
id name
1  John
```

Table fav_pets:

```
id pet
1  cat
1  dog
```

Table fav_colors:

```
id pet
1  red
1  white
1  green
```

## Problem

I want a SQL query that returns this:

```
id  name  pet  color
1   john  cat  red
1   john  dog  white
1   john  null green
```

The problem is if I do:

```
select * from main 
outer join fav_pets on main.id=pet.id 
outer join fav_colors on main.id=fav_colors.id;
```

It will return a result set with 6 rows:

```
id  name  pet  color
1   john  cat  red
1   john  cat  white
1   john  cat  green
1   john  dog  red
1   john  dog  white
1   john  dog  green
```

Can I accomplish the loading of the object without repeating rows in one SQL query?

Comment: Which DBMS do you (intend) to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently joining unlike entities on primary key. You need to join on foreign keys. If John can have favorite pets and favorite colors, then the main table should have columns for `fav_pet_id` and `fav_color_id` that are foreign key-ed to `fav_pet.id` and `fav_color.id`. You also need to change the column name in fav_colors from `pet` to `color`. Once those changes are in place, your query should look like:

```
select main.name, fav_pets.pet, fav_colors.color 
from main 
left outer join fav_pets on main.pet_id=pet.id 
left outer join fav_colors on main.color_id=fav_colors.id;
```

Read up on table normalization, primary keys, and foreign keys. Start at this link for getting started https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp.